# What SQL Server (T-SQL) Query can fetch this result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a dataset with 40,000 records. The format is as shown below.

```
Title  | Publication Date
-------|-----------------
Book-A |   2016-10-20
Book-A |   2017-08-14
Book-B |   2016-09-22
Book-B |   2017-03-16
Book-B |   2017-11-26
Book-C |   2016-06-13
Book-C |   2017-04-15
Book-C |   2016-11-23
Book-C |   2017-12-28
```

I want the SQL query to return **unique book titles** with the **latest publication date**  (like below)

```
Title  | Publication Date
-------|-----------------
Book-A |   2017-08-14
Book-B |   2017-11-26
Book-C |   2017-12-28
```

What will be the T-SQL query to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT [Title],
       Max([Publication Date]) [Publication Date]
FROM   [DataSet]
GROUP  BY [Title]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a rank analytic function:

```
SELECT Title, [Publication Date]
FROM
(
    SELECT Title, [Publication Date],
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Title ORDER BY [Publication Date] DESC) rank
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rank = 1
ORDER BY Title;
```

This approach would capture mutliple records for a given title should a tie occur for the latest date.  If you insist on a single latest record per title, you can replace `RANK` with `ROW_NUMBER`.  Better yet, keep `RANK` and add logic to the `ORDER BY` clause which breaks the tie.

Comment: Yeah. Multiple records are being captured. I have to check remaining columns now.

Comment: Then change `RANK` to `ROW_NUMBER`, but realize then that there are multiple latest records for some titles.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregate funcion `MAX()` like

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
    Title [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    PublicationDate [datetime] NULL
)

Insert into Table1 values('Book-A', '2016-10-20')
Insert into Table1 values('Book-A', '2017-08-14')
Insert into Table1 values('Book-A', '2016-09-22')
Insert into Table1 values('Book-B', '2017-03-16')
Insert into Table1 values('Book-B', '2017-11-26')
Insert into Table1 values('Book-C', '2016-06-13')
Insert into Table1 values('Book-C', '2017-04-15')
Insert into Table1 values('Book-C', '2016-11-23')
Insert into Table1 values('Book-C', '2017-12-28')

Select Title, format(Max(PublicationDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as [Publication Date]
from Table1 group by Title

Drop Table Table1
```